# Is there a formatting expression I can use to insert a decimal point into a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater that includes ICD9 codes as one of the values:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptDRGGrouper">
       <HeaderTemplate>
           <table>
           <tr>
              <th>ICD9 Code</th>
              <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
             <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ICD9Code").ToString()%></td>
             <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description").ToString()%></td>
         </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The ICD9 Codes here have no formatting to them. I would like to add some so that

```
V5789   // current output
V57.89  // desired output
```

A decimal should be added after the third character (if there is a 4th character). e.g.

```
496   becomes 496 // no change
3051  becomes 305.1
v5789 becomes v57.89
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken at face value, I'd create an extension method for this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ICD9Format(this string input)
    {
        //check easy cases first
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || input.Length <= 3)
        {
            return input;
        }

        return input.Insert(3, ".");
    }
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
<td>
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ICD9Code").ToString().ICD9Format()%>
</td>
```

This is assuming there are no other special rules for this sort of formatting.

Comment: Just be sure to import the extensions class to your aspx page so it is available